# Timestamp of when request was submitted from client

Tags: javascript, php, http

So when an event takes place in the client browser, it sends a log request to the server. I wanna get the timestamp of the event as close to real as possible. However, we discovered we cannot trust getting this from Javascript because some browsers have bogus times, like this morning a browser sent us a timestamp from sometime in the year 2000.

The next best thing would be to get the time the request was initiated. Right now we have the timestamp set to be the time the request was received, since we can only trust the server.

I need the timestamp to be trustworthy and as close to the time of the creation of the HTTP request as possible.

Server runs on PHP 5.3.3. Thanks

Comment: You do realize that you cannot trust the client for *anything*? And that noone knows when the client's request was initiated except the client?

Comment: Maybe you can send the correct time from the server and compare it on the client withs its time. Then you have an offset to add when sending your log requests. But there are many unknown influences which cant be handled.

Comment: Maybe getting the network latency would be more reliable? The browser may send bogus timestamps but thats fine since I can just subtract the request duration from the server timestamp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK well I realize the solution based on all the feedback is just to stick with what I have, which is logging the timestamp from when the request reached the server. This is as close to the actual event as you can get and still have a trustworthy timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

As Jon told, you cannot trust client inputs. If the difference between request creation on client side and request receiving at your side is so vital for you, you can try to adjust your timestamp using netspeed databases (for example, https://www.maxmind.com/en/netspeed)

Answer (score 0):

All this should already be logged for you in the apache or ngninx access.log. You may need to enable it, but that is your easiest option. If you insist on making a php log, simply do the following:

```
<?php
file_put_contents("mylog.log",new DateTime() . " - {$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']} visited.\n");
?>
```

somewhere within the page you want to log. You will have to add some unique identifier though, perhaps IP address or some session ID or something.

Answer (score -1):

Insert in the form

```
<input type='hidden' name='reqTimeStamp' value='<?php echo time();?>'>
```

Comment: That would be the time the page loaded not the time the event occurred.